# Calculate total of particular column in sql query

Tags: sql

I want to calculate total of particular column

For ex my table must looks like this

```
     Customername  Payment    id    RunningTotal
       a           500        5          5
       b           500        10         10
       c           300        10         7
                  ------              -----------
                   1300                  22
```

I am getting the table but now I want to calculate the total mentioned at the end for the column Payment and RunningTotal.

Comment: I am sure that you tried something and it did not work, right? Could you show us your query?

Comment: Is it possible to add data to the question? It seems unclear from your question what it is you are trying to total.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are getting the above result from table t1, then you can add your sum at the end by using an Union statement. Something like this

```
select Customername, Payment, id, RunningTotal
from t1
union all
select null,sum(payment),null,sum(runningtotal or any total)
from t1
```

This will add total payments and the other total at the end of the result.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT Sum(Payment) AS Total FROM tablename;
```

**Output**: Total = 1300

Answer (score 1):

```
select sum(Payment) as SumPayment, sum(RunningTotal) as SumRunningTotal
from yourTable
```

Answer (score 1):

Without `GROUPBY` clause use `OVER()`

**Example:**
`select Customername, sum(Payment) OVER () AS TotalPayment, id, sum(RunningTotal) over()`
as RunningTotal
from `t1`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to sum all rows, its as simple as:

```
select sum(payment) payment_sum, sum(runningtotal) runningtotal_sum
from customers;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Customername ,id ,sum(Payment) as Payment , sum(RunningTotal) as RunningTotal from Table group by Customername ,id  with rollup
```

Comment: Hi, this is a pretty long query. Could you add a comment explaining to us on how it works?