# Get total of column and row in SQL result

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using the following SQL statement to get logistics costs from the database:

```
SELECT
country,
sum(Costs_Inbound), sum(Costs_Outbound)
FROM Logistics
GROUP BY country
```

The database `(sqlfiddle)` can be found [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2c9fa44/8). All this works fine so far.

---

Now, I want that in the results the **total** of the **columns** and **rows** is also diplayed. Therefore I tried to go with the following solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308849/calculate-total-of-particular-column-in-sql-query):

```
SELECT country, Costs_Inbound, Costs_Outbound
FROM Logistics
UNION ALL
SELECT null,sum(country),null,sum(Costs_Inbound),null,sum(Costs_Outbound)
FROM Logistics
```

Unfortunately, I could not make it work.

Do you know where there is the mistake in my code?

Comment: When UNION/UNION ALL, the two SELECT's must return the same number of coumns, with matching data types.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff OP provided an SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2c9fa44/8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because the first subquery has no `group by` and the two queries have different numbers of columns.

Use [`ROLLUP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html):

```
SELECT country, sum(Costs_Inbound), sum(Costs_Outbound),
       (sum(Costs_Inbound) + sum(Costs_Outbound)) as in_plus_out
FROM Logistics
GROUP BY country WITH ROLLUP;
```

If you want the values in the same row, then use a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT l.country, sum(l.Costs_Inbound), total.total_in, 
       sum(l.Costs_Outbound), total.total_out
FROM Logistics l CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT sum(l.Costs_Inbound) as total_in, sum(l.Costs_Outbound) as total_out
      FROM logistics l
     ) total
GROUP BY l.country, total.total_in, total.total_out;
```

Comment: Thanks Gorden, the ROLLUP works great for the column total. Is there also such a simple way to get the the row total?

Comment: @Michi . . . Just add another expression for the row total.

Comment: To have it well documented I also updated the SQL queries here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2c9fa44/34

Answer (score 1):

You seems want :

```
SELECT country, Costs_Inbound, Costs_Outbound
FROM Logistics
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, SUM(Costs_Inbound), SUM(Costs_Outbound)
FROM Logistics;
```

Comment: Thanks man, the UNION ALL now works great for the column total. Is there also a way to get the the row total?

Comment: @Michi just replace the `NULL` in the second select with `COUNT(*)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this below query: for union/union all the column no should be equal for selection, in your query your columns no are not same

```
SELECT country, Costs_Inbound, Costs_Outbound
FROM Logistics
UNION ALL
SELECT null,sum(Costs_Inbound),sum(Costs_Outbound)
FROM Logistics
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2c9fa44/17

Comment: ha ha ..no it's not a copy at all, first I gave the answer mistakenly one more column was there. And I think someone copy paste my answer.